# If statement satisfied, yet code does not run

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code, it seems that the two variables that the, if statement asks to be matched for it to run, seems to be equal, but it is skipped across.

```
# This program will play the classic game of "Hangman", with a certain amount of times you can fail, in the end telling the user if they have failed or succeeded in guessing the word
# Creating variables for the number of times players can guess and establishing lists for storing letters they have guessed and lists for what they have successfully guessed so far.
lives = 6
word = 'banana'
listGuess = []
wordAsList = list(word)
blanks = '_'*len(word)
blankList = list(blanks)
blankReference = list(blanks)
print('Word: ')
#Printing the blanks in accordance with the number of letters in the word. 
print(' '.join(blanks) +
      '\n')
#Creating a loop that allows the player to continue guessing, (or failing).
while lives != 0 :
    guess = input('Your guess: ')
#Creating certain things the user cannot input.    
    if len(guess.lower()) > 1 :
        print('\n' + 'Try entering only one character.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
    elif guess.lower() == '' or guess.lower() == ' ' :
        print('\n' + 'Try entering a character, you know. From the alphabet.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
    elif guess.lower() in listGuess :
        print('\n' + 'You\'ve already guessed that letter, genius. -1 life.')
        lives = lives - 1
        print('You have', lives, 'lives remaining.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
#Replacing the black dashes with the succefully guessed letter, in a list by comparing it to a list of guessed letters.
    else :
        listGuess.append(guess)
        count = 0
        for letter in word :
            if guess == wordAsList[count] :
                blankList[count] = wordAsList[count]
            count = count + 1
#Telling the user whether their guess was in the word and showing them an updated version of the blanks, containing guessed characters if availible. Also finds if the user successfully guessed the word, or if they failed.
        if blankList == blankReference :
#ERROR HAPPENING HERE^
            print('\n' + 'Bad luck. Your guess was not in the word.')
            lives = lives - 1
            print('You have', lives, 'tries remaining.')
            print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
        elif word != ''.join(blankReference) :
            count = 0
            for item in blankReference :
                item = blankList[count]
                count = count + 1
            if ''.join(blankList) == word :
                print('\n' + ' '.join(blankList))
                print('Congratulations, you have successfully guessed the word and saved the convicted man.')
                quit()
            else :
                print('\n' + 'Your guess was in the word!')
                print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
print('Bad luck! The man is dead. ')
```

My current example is 'banana', obviously but it seems when I enter b, then d - it outputs that the guess was in the word.

[image: Code example]

Comment: You posted too much code. Please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by some of your code:

```
count = 0
for letter in word :
    if guess == wordAsList[count] :
        blankList[count] = wordAsList[count]
    count = count + 1
```

It looks as if we're looping over the word and getting each letter, but we're never using that letter.

In addition, by setting the count to zero, we're only ever correct if we guess the first letter of the word, though I see you're adding 1 later on, so maybe this is intentional.

---

You've spotted where the issue list, but the logic there is sound. The issue if further down where due to blankList not being equal to blankReference, we flow into the elif, then the else which prints out what you see.

I've tried to keep the code as close to your own as possible, hopefully it works and you can see any additional differences.

```
lives = 6
word = 'banana'
listGuess = []
wordAsList = list(word)
blanks = '_'*len(word)
blankList = list(blanks)
print(' '.join(blanks) +
      '\n')
while lives != 0 :
    guess = input('Your guess: ')
    if len(guess.lower()) > 1:
        print('\n' + 'Try entering only one character.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
    elif guess.lower() == '' or guess.lower() == ' ':
        print('\n' + 'Try entering a character, you know. From the alphabet.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
    elif guess.lower() in listGuess:
        print('\n' + 'You\'ve already guessed that letter, genius. -1 life.')
        lives = lives - 1
        print('You have', lives, 'lives remaining.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
    else:
        listGuess.append(guess)
        correct_guess = False
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == wordAsList[i] :
                blankList[i] = wordAsList[i]
                blankList_new = blankList
                correct_guess = True


        if correct_guess == False:
            print('\n' + 'Bad luck. Your guess was not in the word.')
            lives = lives - 1
            if lives == 0:
                print('Bad luck! The man is dead. ')
            else:
                print('You have', lives, 'tries remaining.')
                print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
        elif word == ''.join(blankList):
            print('\n' + ' '.join(blankList))
            print('Congratulations, you have successfully guessed the word and saved the convicted man.')
            quit()
        else:
            print('\n' + 'Your guess was in the word!')
            print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# This program will play the classic game of "Hangman", with a certain amount of times you can fail, in the end telling the user if they have failed or succeeded in guessing the word
# Creating variables for the number of times players can guess and establishing lists for storing letters they have guessed and lists for what they have successfully guessed so far.
lives = 6
val=0
word = 'banana'
listGuess = []
wordAsList = list(word)
blanks = '_'*len(word)
blankList = list(blanks)
blankReference = list(blanks)
print('Word: ')
#Printing the blanks in accordance with the number of letters in the word. 
print(' '.join(blanks) +
      '\n')
#Creating a loop that allows the player to continue guessing, (or failing).
while lives != 0 :
    guess = input('Your guess: ')
#Creating certain things the user cannot input.    
    if len(guess.lower()) > 1 :
        print('\n' + 'Try entering only one character.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
    elif guess.lower() == '' or guess.lower() == ' ' :
        print('\n' + 'Try entering a character, you know. From the alphabet.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
    elif guess.lower() in listGuess :
        print('\n' + 'You\'ve already guessed that letter, genius. -1 life.')
        lives = lives - 1
        print('You have', lives, 'lives remaining.')
        print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
#Replacing the black dashes with the succefully guessed letter, in a list by comparing it to a list of guessed letters.
    else :
        listGuess.append(guess)
        count = 0
        for letter in word :
            if guess == wordAsList[count] :
                blankList[count] = wordAsList[count]
                val=val+1
            count = count + 1
#Telling the user whether their guess was in the word and showing them an updated version of the blanks, containing guessed characters if availible. Also finds if the user successfully guessed the word, or if they failed.
        if val == 0 :
#ERROR HAPPENING HERE^
            print('\n' + 'Bad luck. Your guess was not in the word.')
            lives = lives - 1
            print('You have', lives, 'tries remaining.')
            print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
        elif word != ''.join(blankReference) :
            count = 0
            for item in blankReference :
                item = blankList[count]
                count = count + 1
            if ''.join(blankList) == word :
                print('\n' + ' '.join(blankList))
                print('Congratulations, you have successfully guessed the word and saved the convicted man.')
                quit()
            else :
                print('\n' + 'Your guess was in the word!')
                print(' '.join(blankList) + '\n')
        val=0
print('Bad luck! The man is dead. ')
```

TESTED ON MY PC ITS WORKING.... I hope this will help u :)

Comment: Just edited 4 places added a new variable val.... actually your concept was totally wrong... you were trying to compare [b,_ ,_ , _ , _ , _ ]==[ _ , _ , _ , _ , _ , _ ]